# How can I change the Service Account that my GCP GAE Flex Service is running as?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm wondering if I can configure a GAE Flexible "service" to use a specific service account ID instead of the default service account ID, which all services run as.

Why? I want to isolate each service's permissions, but also simplify the service code by allowing it to still use the [Application Default credentials method of calling Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

Is there an app.yaml configuration/environment variable where I can control this?

I didn't see the answer here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating
or 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/authorizing-apps

I also found this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using which tells me how to do what I want at the compute engine level, but I don't see how to apply it at the GAE Flex managed level.

If this is not possible, what is the next best alternative?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. Have you found any solution or workaround?

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for solution to do the same .. still searching

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at the moment. The best way to go forward with this would be to open a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: AFAIK this would be the thread to follow: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131854740

Comment: this feature is available https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/user-managed-service-accounts